# SQL Server - When selecting how to propagate values on the top level of a tree? (SQL Fiddle included)

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, propagation

I need to propagate values on top level of tree:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[area](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [parent_id] [int] NULL,
    [color] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [priority] [int] NULL)

insert into area values('root', NULL, NULL, NULL);
insert into area values('test1', 1, NULL, NULL);
insert into area values('test2', 2, 'red', 50);
insert into area values('test3', 5, 'blue', 1);
insert into area values('test4', 1, 'yellow', 10);
```

| id | parent_id | name | color | priority | level | path_id | path_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | (null) | root | (null) | (null) | 0 | 1 | root |
| 2 | 1 | test1 | (null) | (null) | 1 | 1\2 | root\test1 |
| 5 | 1 | test4 | yellow | 10 | 1 | 1\5 | root\test4 |
| 4 | 5 | test3 | blue | 1 | 2 | 1\5\4 | root\test4\test3 |
| 3 | 2 | test2 | red | 50 | 2 | 1\2\3 | root\test1\test2 |

I am doing this with the following query (with CTE for next process):

```
WITH tPATH
AS (SELECT id,
           parent_id,
           name,
           color,
           priority,
           0 as [level],
           CAST(id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) As path_id,
           CAST(name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) As path_name
    FROM area
    WHERE parent_id is NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT area.id,
           area.parent_id,
           area.name,
           area.color,
           area.priority,
           [level] + 1,
           CONCAT(tPATH.path_id, '\', CAST(area.id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))),
           CONCAT(tPATH.path_name, '\', CAST(area.name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
    FROM area
        INNER JOIN tPATH
            ON area.parent_id = tPATH.id
   )
select *
from tPATH;
```

Priority 1 is the best. So I want this:

- blue must be in id 1 with priority 1,
- red must be in id 2 with priority 50,
- blue must be in id 5  with priority 1,
- id 4 and 3 remain unchanged.

| id | parent_id | name | color | priority | level | path_id | path_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | (null) | root | blue | 1 | 0 | 1 | root |
| 2 | 1 | test1 | red | 50 | 1 | 1\2 | root\test1 |
| 5 | 1 | test4 | blue | 1 | 1 | 1\5 | root\test4 |
| 4 | 5 | test3 | blue | 1 | 2 | 1\5\4 | root\test4\test3 |
| 3 | 2 | test2 | red | 50 | 2 | 1\2\3 | root\test1\test2 |

Any idea to do that (propagate color and priority on top level)? [The fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/01287/17) || [SQLize](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/ca2ddda67f6dcf4f589aebad858ed9c1/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking here. Your SQL returns the dataset in your question. What is the problem here? What are you asking? What about your attempt isn't working? What are you expected results is not the table you have in the question?

Comment: Larnu, sorry, I have now created the expected table. The highest priority color blue is propagated on the top nodes. But also the red color replaced the yellow color less priority on its top node. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: The fiddle :  ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Comment: Sqlfiddle seems to be down... An alternative: [SQLize](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/ca2ddda67f6dcf4f589aebad858ed9c1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute an effective priority as a minimum over all node desendants with the query

```
WITH tPATH
AS (SELECT id, 
           id [top],
           parent_id,
           priority
    FROM area

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT area.id, 
           [top],
           area.parent_id,
           area.priority
    FROM area
    INNER JOIN tPATH
            ON area.parent_id = tPATH.id
   )
select [top] as id, min(priority) effective_priority
from tPATH
group by [top];
```

Comment: Thanks! It's works. But I need a lot of code to get my table. I post my code below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Serg's answer, I created this code which gives me the expected result. Can it be simpler ?

```
WITH tPATH
AS (SELECT id,
           parent_id,
           name,
           color,
           priority,
           0 [level],
           CAST(id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [path_id],
           CAST(name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [path_name]
    FROM area
    WHERE parent_id is NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT area.id,
           area.parent_id,
           area.name,
           area.color,
           area.priority,
           [level] + 1,
           CONCAT(tPATH.path_id, '\', CAST(area.id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))),
           CONCAT(tPATH.path_name, '\', CAST(area.name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
    FROM area
        INNER JOIN tPATH
            ON area.parent_id = tPATH.id
   ),
     tDIFF
AS (SELECT id,
           id [top],
           parent_id,
           priority
    FROM area
    UNION ALL
    SELECT area.id,
           [top],
           area.parent_id,
           area.priority
    FROM area
        INNER JOIN tDIFF
            ON area.parent_id = tDIFF.id
   ),
     tDIFFEND
AS (select [top] as id,
           min(priority) effective_priority
    from tDIFF
    group by [top]
   )
SELECT tPATH.id,
       tPATH.parent_id,
       tPATH.name,
       area.color,
       effective_priority [priority],
       tPATH.level,
       tPATH.path_id,
       tPATH.path_name
from tPATH
    INNER JOIN tDIFFEND
        ON tDIFFEND.id = tPATH.id
    LEFT JOIN area
        ON area.priority = effective_priority;
```